# How access value from data class which is inside a data class

Tags: android, kotlin

```
data class A(
  val type: Int,
  val data: Any
) {
  data class B(
    val name: String,
    val phone: String
  )
  data class C(
    val name: String,
    val phone: String
  )
}
```

How to access data of class B and C??

Comment: _val b = A.B("name", "phone")_

Comment: i need to access value from B and C into recycler adapter according to position list[position].data then after data not getting any object or value

Comment: B and C are classes, not instances.

Comment: yes data classes

Comment: Well, classes do not contain values, instances do.

Comment: ok can u please explain more because data is of any type instance can set value for both of the classes using data and can get value using data or not .. or help if having opiton to access data of B and C in adapter

Comment: above shared class is my modle class in which i am able to set data and having list of data and now i need to get those data into adapter like list[position].data. then after data. how i will get instance of B and C .

Comment: One question: is _val data: Any_ of _class A_ holding instances of class _B_ and _C_?

Comment: yes expecting that similar to Java Object class

Comment: Well, your question should mention that. It was not clear from reading the code.

Comment: Why are there two classes, B and C, with the identical properties? Delete class C and change _val data: Any_ to _val data: B_

Comment: that is same only for exp only but if their will be 5 class B to F or only B or c their must be different data for both class or for all classes.. properties will be different always ..

Comment: But then your sample code is useless. It is difficult to answer, when the code posted in the question is misleading.

Comment: No issue and also multiple classes or different classes can have same property that's not the big deal . if things will work for different properties then will work for same properties  also..

Answer (score 0):

I would create a parent class for the nested classes:

```
data class A(
  val type: Int,
  val data: Data
) {

  abstract class Data(
    open val name: String,
    open val phone: String
  )

  data class B(
    override val name: String,
    override val phone: String,
    val moreInfo: String
  ): Data(name, phone)

  data class C(
    override val name: String,
    override val phone: String,
    val otherInfo: String
  ): Data(name, phone)

}

val list = listOf(
  A(1, A.B("name B1", "phone 1", "more info 1")),
  A(2, A.B("name B2", "phone 2", "more info 2")),
  A(3, A.C("name C1", "phone 3", "other info 1")),
  A(3, A.B("name B3", "phone 4", "more info 3"))
)

// no casting necessary for properties of the data class "Data"
println(list[1].data.name)
println(list[2].data.phone)

// casting necessary for properties in the data classes "B" and "C
println((list[1].data as A.B).moreInfo)
println((list[2].data as A.C).otherInfo)

// (smart) casting with if clause
for (item in list) {
  if (item.data is A.B) {
    println(item.data.moreInfo)   // smart casting
  } else if (item.data is A.C) {
    println(item.data.otherInfo)   // smart casting
  } else {
    // maybe raise an exception here
  }
}

// (smart) casting with when clause
for (item in list) {
  when (item.data) {
    is A.B -> println(item.data.moreInfo)
    is A.C -> println(item.data.otherInfo)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access like this

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    val a = A(
        type = 1,
        data = "String"
    )
        println("$a")
        
        val b = A.B(
         name = "B",
         phone = "123456789"   
        )
        println("$b")
        
        val c = A.C(
         name = "c",
         phone = "987654321"   
        )
        
        println("$c")


}

data class A(
  val type: Int,
  val data: Any
) {
  data class B(
    val name: String,
    val phone: String
  )
  data class C(
    val name: String,
    val phone: String
  )
}
```

//Output

```
Hello, world!!!
A(type=1, data=String)
B(name=B, phone=123456789)
C(name=c, phone=987654321)
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer now afer few tries ..

val b:A.B = list[position].data as A.B

val c:A.C = list[position].data as A.C

Thanks every one for your quick answer and discussoin.